# Iterate through nested dict, check bool values to get indexes of array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dict with boolean values, like:

```
assignments_dict = {"first": {'0': True,
                              '1': True},
                    "second": {'0': True,
                               '1': False},
                    }
```

and an array, with a number of elements equal to the number of True values in the assignments_dict:

```
results_array = [10, 11, 12]
```

and, finally, a dict for results structured this way:

```
results_dict = {"first": {'0': {'output': None},
                          '1': {'output': None}},
                "second": {'0': {'output': None},
                           '1': {'output': None}},
                }
```

I need to go through the fields in assignment_dict, check if they are True, and if they are take the next element of results_array and substitute it to the corresponding field in results_dict. So, my final output should be:

```
results_dict = {'first': {'0': {'output': 10},
                          '1': {'output': 11}},
                'second': {'0': {'output': 12},
                           '1': {'output': None}}}
```

I did it in a very simple way:

```
# counter used to track position in array_outputs
counter = 0
for outer_key in assignments_dict:
    for inner_key in assignments_dict[outer_key]:
        # check if every field in assignments_dict is True/false
        if assignments_dict[outer_key][inner_key]:
            results_dict[outer_key][inner_key]["output"] = results_array[counter]
            # move on to next element in array_outputs
            counter += 1
```

but I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way to solve this.

Comment: Python dictionaries are not ordered, i.e, it can easily happen that "second" appears as the first element in the iteration. Same for the lower level. Your logic seems to depend on the ordering of the second level's values. So you have to make sure that it is correct. Use an `OrderedDict`, for example.

Comment: @MaxPowers: dicts are ordered since 3.7

Comment: @Swifty, thanks; that has completely passed me by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
results_iter = iter(results_array)
for key, value in assignments_dict.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
        if inner_value:
            results_dict[key][inner_key]['output'] = next(results_iter)


print(results_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': {'0': {'output': 10}, '1': {'output': 11}}, 'second': {'0': {'output': 12}, '1': {'output': None}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Leaving the problem of the order of the dictionaries aside, you can do the following:

```
it_outputs = iter(array_outputs)
for k, vs in results_dict.items():
    for ki, vi in vs.items():
        vi["output"] = next(it_outputs) if assignments_dict[k][ki] else None


print(results_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'first': {'0': {'output': 10}, '1': {'output': 11}}, 'second': {'0': {'output': 12}, '1': {'output': None}}}
```

Note that dictionaries keep insertion order since Python 3.7.

Comment: To be precise, Python dicts already kept insertion order before 3.7, but it used to be an implementation detail. Starting with 3.7, it's guaranteed by the contract. But since the past is immutable, it can now be relied on in every version of Python.